# mysql how to query list of posts and its multiple tags which are in different tables

Tags: mysql, tags

**What i have is:**

1. I have a tables like images, tags, tag_names and downloads
2. In which images can have multiple tags and are in separate tables
3. downloads table will maintain the total downloads of an image

*and by now i hope you would have understood the purpose of my table definition*

---

**What i need is:**

1. my need is to display the tags when i do a listing of all images. for example i am displaying 10 images in one page and below each image i want to display all their tags. (*assuming this is not possible in one query result. if so then other means would be nice*)
2. when i display a single image as a separate page like a blog post page i want all the tags to be displayed like in stackoverflow.

---

**Table structures are:**

***images table***

imageid | name |

1 | sample1

2 | sample2

3 | sample3

4 | sample3

...............................

***tagnames table***

tagid | name

1 | tagname1

2 | tagname2

3 | tagname3

4 | tagname3

...............................

***tags table***

id | imageid | tagid

1 | 1 | 1

2 | 1 | 2

3 | 1 | 3

4 | 2 | 1

5 | 3 | 4

...............................

***downloads table***

id | imageid | downloads

1 | 1 | 5

1 | 2 | 3

...............................

note: ... other images does not have a reference in this table but images will sure have at least one tag

Here i have a performance question for downloads table. whether to add a row for each download by having just id and imageid in downloads table or to have another field and to increment it like in the table example above - maybe i should ask this as a separate question and if so then please ignore this paragraph.

---

**So if that could be possible then suggest/advice me else please suggest alternatives.**

Comment: Don't you already have images v/s tags information in your tags table? simply run `select` queries on that .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select image_name, GRP_CONCAT(tag_name)
from images, tags, tagnames
where tags.image_id = images.image_id
and tags.tag_id = tagnames.tag_id 
group by image_name
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

The query should return image name, and all the tags it has in a comma seperated string.
Kindly refer to Group_CONCAT() function documentation, and confirm the syntax. You can also change the delimeter.

Comment: ah. thats a nice thought. besides, is this how stackoverflow would have done it... no problem anyway... . i want to link those tags to a resource using their id... for this i think i have to some code in php... like exploding that into array and writing a foreach to display and link each tag... isn't it? what do you say?

Comment: besides i want to include downloads table. is it ok to use implicit joins like your example. do we have to use explicit joins (i have read people suggesting to use standard query in my previous org.)? besides i confuse a lot with query making so i am not sure of asking JOIN to fit here.